# Using existing iOS Developer Certificate for Trigger.io iphone development

Tags: trigger.io

I am currently following this link to test the trigger.io iOS build on my iphone but have run into a problem. I have an existing IOS Developer Certificate in the iOS provisioning portal and so cannot upload the new certificate?

I dont want to rmeove this certificate as i have existing apps in the app store using it.

So my question is can i use my existing certificate to test the build on my iPhone? When i download and install my certificate and then try to export it, i can not export it in .pfx format?

Edit: I am trying to do this on a windows machine.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Mac for this? In that case, you don't need to export your certificate at all: we use ones installed in your Keychain automatically.

By default, we pick up one with a name beginning "iPhone Developer", but you can also override this (if you have several certificates) with the `developer_certificate` parameter.

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/tools/local-config.html#ios

Comment: No sorry, i'm trying to do this on Windows?

Comment: @Mike try downloading it from the developer portal, then install it and finally export it using certmgr.msc here is more information on that http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/tools/ios-windows.html?highlight=certmgr